# Disabling submit button file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, simple-form, filefield

I have a file_field option where I navigate to a csv file to upload a series of users. I currently am able to click on the upload users button without a file being added. I want to ensure that I catch this nil exception but cant seem to work out how to do it. Should I change my controller or change the form by disabling the button somehow

I have the following simple form for uploading a file:

```
<%= simple_form_for :tenant, :html => {:multipart => true}, :url => users_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :csv, :label => 'CSV File' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Upload Users' %>
<% end %>
```

I have the following view following in the controller:

```
def upload
  if request.post?
    if params[:tenant][:csv].blank?
      flash[:notice] = "Please provide a csv file to upload."
    else
      file = params[:tenant][:csv].read   
      CSV.parse(file, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol).each { |row| User.create(row.to_hash) }
    end 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end    
  else
    # Return view
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either do client side validation or server side.  I'd recommend server side as a starting point.  Based on what I see in your controller it looks like you do not have a model for the csv upload.  It is better practice to refactor your controller csv code into a model as the logic does not belong in the controller.  Once you have a model for the csv upload,

> validates_presence_of :file

in the model should do the trick.

If you are not familiar with table less models checkout the railscast #219.